# How to drop the constant from ARMA model?

Tags: python

Im estimating an ARMA model, with exegenous variables. The default model estimates it with a constant, but it is insignificant and I would like to drop the constant from my model. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide the code you're using to estimate the model and try to make it as concise as possible ([mcve]).

Comment: Thats my code: 
modelo1 = ARMA(base_final['PIM_yoy'], 
               exog=pd.concat([base_final['Anfavea_yoy'], base_final['ABPO_yoy'], base_final['IBS_Aço_yoy'], base_final['Funcex_m_yoy'], base_final['CNI5_yoy']],
                              axis=1).astype(float), order=(3, 1), missing='drop')